# Error Package to install apache and php5 on RHEL 6.3

Tags: php, apache, rhel6

I am trying to install Apache and PHP5 on RHEL 6.3 but I have not succeeded yet. When I try to add the Remi, EPEL repositories and run

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

it delivers a dependency failure:

```
Error: Package: libevent-last-2.0.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pdo-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-process-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: gd-last-2.1.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mysqlnd-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: libevent-last-2.0.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: gd-last-2.1.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libXpm.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-apcu-4.0.7-2.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libXpm.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.12.5-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.6.10-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-xml-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.9.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pgsql-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-3.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-xml-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-common-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.2.1-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libt1.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.6-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libt1.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.6-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.6.10-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pgsql-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libpq.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-common-5.5.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.7-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Is it necessary to use yum repositories to register channels redhat?
What may the error be?

I am adding EPEL and remi as follows.

### Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

### CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to yum trying to pull el7 package (for CentOS 7) which are not designed to work on CentOS 6

Check your yum configuration for remi-php55 repository.

Also notice, than "remi" repository packages are currently build for 6.6 (or 6.7), and could not work as expected with older versions (6.3 according to question title) especially because of openssl update. So you also have to start by an update to latest CentOS (yum update)